# Get Long and Lat from device

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I have android application, I want to send my ***exactly*** long,lat.
I already tried this code :

```
 private TextView txt;
        private double lng,lat;
        private CharSequence message;
        LocationManager lm,locationManager;
          TextView lt, ln;
          String provider;
          Location l;

     ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
            lt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
            //get location service
            lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria c=new Criteria();

            provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
            //now you have best provider
            //get location
            l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if(l!=null)
            {
              //get latitude and longitude of the location
              double lng=l.getLongitude();
              double lat=l.getLatitude();
              //display on text view
              ln.setText(""+lng);
              lt.setText(""+lat);
            }
            else
            {
             ln.setText("No Provider");
             lt.setText("No Provider");
            }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            lng=l.getLongitude();
            lat=l.getLatitude();
            ln.setText(""+lng);
            lt.setText(""+lat);
        }
```

My resualt is :`No provider` ..Thanks for help . 
Actualy it works before few days, I dont know how but now it doesnt.. and

*** I did all the permissions and turn on the GPS ***
**EDIT :**
I found my problem, I missed the line :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Now it gives me variables, it close to my real location but it doesnt good enough, how can I do it exactly ?

Comment: because your last known location is null, there is no guarantee that there will always be a cached location. Plus it could be an old out of date location which isnt exact like you want

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/